# How to make Sublime Text 3 execute a written program?

Tags: c, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

Sublime Text 3 doesn't support user input so lets say in C I want to work a bit with scanf and not use IDEs, instead stay on SB3, how do I make it execute the program?

Comment: Can you please expand on what you are trying to do a little more?  Perhaps an example?

Comment: Sure, here is an example:

#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int a, b;
printf("Insert two numbers: ");
scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);     /*<<<So this is the part where I need to enter an input, but defaulty (I guess) I cannot onSublime Text 3.

printf("%d - %d = %d\n ", a, b, a-b);
return (0);
}

Comment: https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-run-a-C-program-in-sublime-text-2

Answer (score 0):

Compile and run your program from the command line.